# SharePoint 2010 approval task locked

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, workflow, tasks

When I am running the workflow, sometimes I get this error for particular item:

> 'This task is currently locked by a running workflow and cannot be edited'.

How can we solve the above error?

Please share the solution.

Comment: Are you using any task action in your workflow and updating the same task in your workflow? Can you please add screenshots of actions you used in workflow?

Comment: Please check if the Due Date of the task is in the past(less than today), it might cause this issue some times.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the nature of your WF. Are you doing update to that task in wf? if so you need put a wait action after it. Sometimes WF is faster than sharepoint due to async calls and hits race condition. Put a 5 min wait after update of the task and see if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When a workflow processes a task normally, the following sequence of events is expected to occur:

1. The process begins.
2. The workflow places a ‘lock’ on the task so nothing else can change the values while the workflow is processing.
3. The workflow processes the task.
4. The lock is released when the task processing is finished.

When the message is encountered, it usually indicates that an error occurred between step 2 and 4. As a result, the lock is never released.

Try to stop workflow and start new workflow for the item